# Motor Controller Cloning Service?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, motor-controller

I am a total amateur and seek the hardware engineer wizards that frequent this website, lol.

Anyway, does there exist a service to clone a PCB given just a few pictures?

Does a service exist that will manufacture a PCB + install components if given a complete schematic?

My problem: LunaCycle is notoriously fickle about selling their Ludicrous v2 motor controller. However, they do provide a lot of information and pictures on their release page. How feasible is it that someone could look at their design, layout all the same components, and send that information to a PCB manufacturer?

Who will clone this device for sale to general public?

(https://lunacycle.com/blog/luna-bbshd-ludicrous-v2-released/)

I know it’s a longshot, but I apprecite any feedback on this idea.

Comment: that's like asking to copy an automobile from just a few pictures

Comment: :( understandable, have a nice day

Comment: Internal software won't appear on a photograph

Comment: One thing is that this thing runs on VESC, an open source software popular with electric skateboards. Not that I know how to flash the chip or anything, but the fact that it’s open source makes it easier to get started

Comment: _"Who will clone this device for sale to general public?"_ - someone in a country that doesn't respect copyright law?

Comment: Is the ludicrous vesc better than trampa vesc? Maybe just buy some other vesc, if luna won't sell to you. Part of the problem right now may be that the ST Micro controllers are on back order everywhere. Maybe that is why Luna is so fickle? You may not do better going the DIY route.

Comment: The Luna VESC is better than a normal VESC because it fits inside of the stock housing. I’m going to use a BAC-855 for this project, but would rather have a solution that doesn’t require an externally mounted controller.

Comment: You guys and a Karan at KickrDesign have basically spelled it out for me: This request is essentially impossible unless I was a hardcore hardware engineer and had the resources to reverse engineer the thing myself, as well as additional skills / resources to manufacture a clone. So it’s in no way possible. Thanks for the input, gents!

Answer (score 2):

> ...they do provide a lot of information and pictures on their release
> page. How feasible is it that someone could look at their design,
> layout all the same components, and send that information to a PCB
> manufacturer?

There isn't enough information on their website to determine the exact circuit or which components were used. However the [VESC](https://vesc-project.com/) design whose firmware it uses is fully open-source, so anyone sufficiently 'experienced in the art' could design a compatible circuit and board with similar components.

> Who will clone this device for sale to general public?

I'm guessing nobody. This upgrade is apparently not legal for use on public streets or trails in the US, so the market is quite limited. Probably only a few hardcore off-road bikers will be interested, and many of them might prefer to get the real deal rather than a dodgy clone. There could be legal issues too, if the clone is too close a copy of the original (PCB layouts are protected by copyright). It would be a risky venture with little chance of getting a worthwhile ROI.